# Servicestack include _Layout.cshtml in Razor Content Page

Tags: asp.net, razor, servicestack, servicestack-razor

How can I include _Layout.cshtml in Razor Content Page ?

For example I created two cshtml files in root of my project.

First file is _Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Main Layout</h1>
    <br>
    <br>   
    @RenderBody();    
</body>
</html>
```

Second File is Product.cshtml

```html
@inherits ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage

@{ 
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

}

    <h1>Product Page</h1>
```

When I call http://localhost:6000/product

The result is in browser is

```
Product Page
```

but it should be

```
Main Layout

Product Page
```

Why ? 
What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout names should be the name of the file not a path and you should never need to reference `_Layout` as it's the default.

Also if you want your Views and Content Pages to share the same `_Layout.cshtml` pages add them once to `/Views/_Layout.cshtml` or `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` instead.

If this is Self hosting HttpListener project you need to ensure all `*.cshtml` are set to **Copy to Output Directory** or the [WebHostPhysicalPath references your project path](http://docs.servicestack.net/self-hosting#serving-razor-views-or-static-files-from-httplistener).